# change the embedded value on another collection when change the original collection data on mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I have collection that called City and I have some embedded  information of this collection in other Collections

I embed some of city's property in customer collection

**City.schema**

```
@Schema({ collection: 'city', virtuals: true, _id: false })

export class City  {
  @Prop({ type: String })
  imageName: string;
  @Prop({ index: true, type: String })
  enName: string;
  @Prop({ type: String, unique: true })
  instagram: string;

}
```

**Base City**

this is part of city that I want to embed that in other collections

```
export class BaseCity extends Document {
  @Prop({
    type: String,
    required: true,
  })
  _id: string;
  @Prop({ type: String })
  enName: string;
}
```

and I want to embed part data of city on the customer schema with base city

**customer.schema**

```
@Schema({ collection: 'customer', validateBeforeSave: true, timestamps: true })
export class Customer extends Document {
  @Prop({
    type: String,
  })
  emailAddress: string;

  @Prop({ type: String })
  compare: string;

  @Prop({ ref: BaseCity.name, type: BaseCity })
  city: BaseCity;

  @Prop({ type: [String] })
  jobIdHistory: string[];
}
```

when i change city collection, i want to update embedded field in customer automatically

If there is no automatic way in MongoDB, please state your suggested ways